# Add static directory between two variable segments . URL rewriting .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm rewriting my PHP website `URLs` in `.htaccess`
Its working fine for most cases like

```
RewriteRule  ^featured/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$   featured.php?cat=$1  [NC,L]
```

is working and now I have a case..

```
RewriteRule  ^featured/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/page/([0-9-]+)/?$   featured.php?cat=$1?page=$2  [NC,L]
```

here is ***[url of the page](https://stcjapan.net/Featured/Brand-New-Vehicles/page/2)*** 
first argument is being echoed as ***Brand-New-Vehicles?page=2***
I need it to be ***Brand-New-Vehicles***

The segment after featured will be variable and then static segment `/page/` and then variable page number. it should lead to featured.php?cat={first variable}?page={second variable}

Comment: Your question is pretty good. Also your 2nd rule looks good. Is it not working?

Comment: yes it is not working.

Comment: Provide details of not working. What URL did your enter in browser and what error are you getting?

Comment: Ok , editing my question

Comment: have updated my question..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180759/discussion-between-nadeem-gorsi-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^featured/([a-z\d-]+)/page/([\d-]+)/?$ featured.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Instead of `&` you have another `?` in target.